# WPF MVVM Command not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i develop a app in WPF using prism 6. I try to update the date time with this command. I try to update the code without any successes.

EDIT 1:
Added Code from the former Link to Onedrive

Classes:

```
 public class Employee : BindableBase
{
    private int _id;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }

        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _id, value);
        }
    }

    private string _firstName ="YehudaEmp";

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set {SetProperty(ref _firstName , value); }
    }

    private string _lastName="DnaiEmp";
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _lastName, value);
        }
    }

    private int _phone;
    public int Phone
    {
        get
        {
            return _phone;
        }

        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _phone, value);
        }
    }

    private string _email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _email, value);
        }
    }

    private string _city;
    public string  City
    {
        get { return _city; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _city, value);
        }
    }

    private string _street;
    public string Street
    {
        get { return _street; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _street, value);
        }
    }


    private string _state;
    public string State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _state, value);
        }
    }

    private DateTime? _lastUpdate;
    public DateTime? LastUpdate
    {
        get { return _lastUpdate; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _lastUpdate, value);
        }
    }     
}

public class EmployeeViewModel :BindableBase
{

    private Employee emop;


   public string FirstName
    {
        get { return emop.FirstName; }
        set
        {
            emop.FirstName = value;
        }

    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return emop.LastName; }
        set
        {
            emop.LastName = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime? lastUpdated
    {
        get { return emop.LastUpdate; }
        set
        {
            emop.LastUpdate = value;
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand updateCommand { get; set; }


    public EmployeeViewModel()
    {

       emop = new Employee();
        updateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute , canExecute).ObservesProperty(()=>FirstName).ObservesProperty(() =>LastName);
    }

    private bool canExecute()
    {
      return  !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName);
    }

    private void Execute()
    {

       lastUpdated = DateTime.Now;

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="195" Height="30" Margin="5" Text="{Binding FirstName ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="195" Height="30" Margin="5" Text="{Binding LastName , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastUpdated,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20"/>
            <Button Name="updatebtn" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" Height="30" Margin="5" Content="update" Command="{Binding updateCommand,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

any help ?

Comment: Place the code direct into the question

Comment: Why you don't bind on the `Employee.Name`? This would be the right way in my opinion.

Comment: Can `Command` have `Mode` set to `TwoWay`?  I expect that to produce a binding error, but I've never tried, so I don't know for sure.  Check the output window when that form loads to make sure you don't see a binding error go flying by about it.  That could be making the binding fail completely.

Comment: Try it not working 10x

Comment: Have you tried removing the `Mode` on the binding so that it is just `Command="{Binding updateCommand}"`?

Comment: Yes i try to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your view model is `EmployeeViewModel` which is bound to the view.

Then, your problem is that your view model is not rising `PropertyChanged` events to the view. You are rising property changed events from your model which is `Employee` and which are not being captured by the view.

You need to raise the events from your view model for the view to capture them.

The method [`BindableBase.SetProperty<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430857(v=pandp.40).aspx) raises the `PropertyChanged` event, so all you need is to move your calls to `SetProperty<T>` from the `Employee` class to the `EmployeeViewModel` class.

So, for example, your `lastUpdated` binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding lastUpdated,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20"/>
```

Should have a corresponding property in the view model that looks like this:

```
private DateTime? m_lastUpdated;

public DateTime? lastUpdated
{
    get { return m_lastUpdated; }
    set { SetProperty<DateTime?>(ref m_lastUpdated, value);
}
```

From an MVVM perspective, you typically don't raise `PropertyChanged` events from the model (`Employee` in your case), the only entity that should communicate with the view is the view model (`EmployeeViewModel` in your case).